# HTML and PHP Form together

Tags: php, html

I want to build html form which would display data from a database. These I want to modify in the action file from my form.

But my construct doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
            <?php
            //include 'readHersteller.php';
            //$hersteller = $resultIDs;
            $hersteller = array ('hersteller 1' , 'hersteller 2'); 
            $herstellerAnzahl = count($hersteller);
            echo '

                <div class="container">
                    <form action="actionHandler.php" method="post">
                        <h2>Hersteller wählen</h2>
                        <p>Wählen Sie hier den hersteller, dessen Produktlieferzeit verändert werden soll.</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sel1">Wählen Sie hier einen der '.$herstellerAnzahl.' Hersteller aus:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                ';
                                foreach ($hersteller as &$value){
                                echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
                                }
            echo '
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <h2> Geben Sie die gewünschte Lieferzeit ein: </h2>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="lieferzeit">Maßanfertigung in 1-3 Wochen bei Ihnen</textarea>
                    <br>
                </form> 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg value="Submit">Absenden</button>
            ';

        ?>
```

I have chosen this echo, because I need the foreeach loop to display my array in the form, then I need to take the value from the textarea and submit both to the actionHandler.php.

That won't work, because the form is divided up because of my echos..

Question: How can I display the php array in the form better, so that I'm able to create one form ?

Comment: first make the string then print `echo` it

Comment: `foreach ($hersteller as &$value){
 echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';` what is this `&$value` it should be `$value`

Comment: Why exactly shouldn't the given code work?

Comment: you forgot to echo the $value for the second time: echo '<option value ="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong with this coding style if you are comfortable.  The resulting html is only one form.  A couple of issues:  your button is outside of the form.  And your form elements are lacking name attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to suggest you a similar solution, but it's going to be totally using `<?php ?>` so that you don't get into the issues of escaping `'` and `"`, which might be harder in these cases.

Also, a few things to note:

1. You have some ill nesting of tags.
2. Your `<button>` tag is malformed, you haven't closed the class value (`"`).
3. Your `<button>` should reside inside the form block, unless you add a corresponding form attribute.
4. You are using a reference in the foreach `&$value` which is not necessary.

Suggested rewrite:

```
<?php
  //include 'readHersteller.php';
  //$hersteller = $resultIDs;
  $hersteller = array(
    'hersteller 1',
    'hersteller 2'
  );
  $herstellerAnzahl = count($hersteller);
?>
<div class="container">
  <form action="actionHandler.php" method="post">
    <h2>Hersteller wählen</h2>
    <p>Wählen Sie hier den hersteller, dessen Produktlieferzeit verändert werden soll.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Wählen Sie hier einen der <?php echo $herstellerAnzahl; ?> Hersteller aus:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <?php
        foreach ($hersteller as $value) {
          echo '<option>' . $value . '</option>';
        }
      ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <h2> Geben Sie die gewünschte Lieferzeit ein: </h2>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="lieferzeit">Maßanfertigung in 1-3 Wochen bei Ihnen</textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit">Absenden</button>      
  </form> 
</div><!-- This should be here. -->
```

Additionally you have no name attributes on your form input elements.  So no data will be submitted currently.

Comment: @Progrock Woah... Thanks. looks like you could have answered it in a better way... `:D` I'll add them up... Or if you would like to edit my answer, I give you all rights... `:D`

Comment: Thank you very much, thats the answer :) I'm so happy now :)

But what's the significant difference? O.o Only the ("") ?

Comment: @Rudi Not only that. A lot. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

```
foreach ($hersteller as &$value){
   echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

to

```
foreach ($hersteller as $value){
   echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

PHP cant Read Variables like &$variablename. I would suggest you, to get an IDE which highlight these errors. Atom is an good one for beginners.

German:
Du solltest dir einen Editor wie Atom anlegen, dieser zeigt dir schnell solch oberflächlichen Erros. Wenn du sonst mal Hilfe brauchst beim Coden, kannst du mich immer auf ts3.sa-countyrp.de erreichen und wir können zusammen die Probleme angehen.

MFG

Comment: This actually works, it's passing the value as a reference, but you only want/need to do that if you want to change the `$value` within the `$hersteller` array, from within the loop.

Comment: What's the difference between the two code samples? The output should be completely the same

Comment: Yes, this is ill advice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But my code works and the answer from @krom says the same, maybe this way is only available in a higher php version?